# cannot destroy labels of my buttons

Tags: c#, forms, label, dispose

i'm developing a "cache image generator" for a company.
the target of this form is to pre-compute all possibles buttons scenario.
it create a couple of custom buttons, take a snapshot, clear everything and redo until it tried them all.

my problem is that i cannot destroy the labels inside my custom buttons.
my custom button is working fine and i can generate the first image.
because i use an index as last part of the labels names the 2nd round will fail due to existing items with the same name, i believe.

this is how i'm trying to destroy everything:

```
foreach (my_button b in this.wrapper.Controls.OfType<my_button>())
{
    b.resume_layout();
    b.show();
}
this.PerformLayout();
bmp = new Bitmap(this.wrapper.Width, this.wrapper.Height);
this.wrapper.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
a.result = bmp;
cc = this.wrapper.Controls;
this.wrapper.Controls.Clear();
foreach (Control C in cc)
    C.Dispose();
cc = null;
GC.Collect();
```

and this is the custom Dispose handler of my_button:

```
    new public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        this.currency_label.Dispose();
        this.name_label.Dispose();
        this.price_label.Dispose();
        this.currency_label = this.name_label = this.price_label = null;
        this.BackgroundImage = null;
        this.Controls.Clear();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

i believe that it's a not-destroying trouble because i randomly get this:
`Illegal cross-thread operation: Control 'control name' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` on the labels Dispose() call.

thanks in advance for any help.

-- EDIT --

i solved.
the problem was a wrong call on my mooremachine framework that set everything Visible=false
please remove this question since it won't be useful.

Comment: `GC.Collect` is never a good idea. I think you want to use `cc.Controls.Remove(c)` (not sure of correct syntax right now)

Comment: Button b = new Button();
ContentControl c = b as ContentControl;
 c.Content = null;

Answer (score 0):

For the reason of cross-thread calling exception, it is because you incorrectly implement `Dispose(bool)`. `Dispose(bool)` can be called from finalizer method and the calling thread for that is unspecified e.g. it could be from any thread.

About the control you added, you do not need to add extra dispose method. The child controls are disposed automatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4zkb31d.aspx

> Control.Dispose Method (Boolean)
>
> Releases the unmanaged resources used by the Control and its child
>   controls and optionally releases the managed resources.

Anyway, you might want to dispose your own bitmap if the bitmap's owner is `my_button` and no other object will use the same bitmap. You can do so as follows:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) {
         var backgroundImage = this.BackgroundImage;
         this.BackgroundImage = null;
         backgroundImage.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

And no need to redeclare `Dispose()` method.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it solve the exception error.  
but i'm not able to change the "Visible" property of my buttons on the 2nd round.  
on the first round my_button are created with Visible = true  
on the second round they are created with the Visible = false, and even if i call b.Visible = true i keep seeing Visible = false in the Immediate Window.  
i updated my question, i think that the main problem is that i cannot create other labels because the older ones ( with the same name ) already exist somewhere.  
thanks again for your help :)